# notepad++ remove new line in " " at my csv-file

Tags: csv, notepad++, newline

My problem is that I have a csv-file with alot of new line. How can I remove the newlines with select and replace? My other stuff should stay how it is.

Here the example:

101080;101080;101080;104;
101098;101098;101098;105;
**101099;101099;101099;106;"RING 750GG 1BRI TW VS 0,0300ct 1 RUBIN WEITE58.0

BREITE 4.5mm

72-91872-0-0 045-71-0-58-3

704.- VP1000.-

";**
1011;1011;1011;106;
101093;101093;101093;123;

I have all over the csv file these new lines. I need to make that in 1 line.

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

1. Activate the ShowAll Icon (¶) in the toolbar of Notepad++
2. Mark a `;` and NewLine-Sequence (`CR` `LF`) in your file
3. Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
4. Select the *Replace* tab in the appeared search window
5. Insert `;` in the *Replace with* text box
6. Press *Replace All*

Now all items ending with a `;` are in single rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you only wish to remove the newlines for any lines that do not end in a semicolon character.  You can do that below with this Find and Replace in Notepad ++ using the Regular Expression Search Mode.

```
Find:  ([^;]$)(\r\n)
Replace:  \1
```

Explanation of the find is that it is looking for the end of line and newline character that isn't preceded by a semicolon character.  The parenthesis tell the find to group the results, which allows us in the replace to just keep the first grouping of find results and to discard the newline characters for these lines that don't end in a semicolon, which will then end up making it all line up on the previous line.

Comment: and how I do that if not all have semicolon? 1011;1011;1011;106
101093;101093;101093;123 , if the end is not all the time a semicolon.

Comment: If the end is not a semicolon all the time I would probably break this into two or more sets of search and replaces and combine the results after.  Otherwise it turns into a lot more complicated problem that may still have fringe scenarios that do not work.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all new lines: Just replace "\r\n" (windows) or "\n" (unix) with nothing! Using Extended or Regex options.

To just remove some:
First add unique data where you want to keep the new line - I use "QAZ".

Then remove all new lines as above.
Then replace "QAZ" with "\n".